# Help identifying a sot-223 ldo voltage regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, ldo

I can't seem to identify this.  It's a 1117c but I need to find the correct output voltage.  I don't recognize the manufacturer logo.  Thanks in advance.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It's a Burr-Brown/TI/AMS/NatSemi [LM1117](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117.pdf) regulator.

Normally, LM1117/AMS1117 family has a wide range of members having fixed outputs (e.g. 1.2V, 1.8V, 3.3V). But probably, this one is the **adjustable** one. To be sure, look for a resistor pair connected to the 1st (leftmost) pin or put a bigger picture showing wider area.

Comment: You sure it's a Burr Brown? That's the first I thought it was but I can't find a 1117c datasheet and it looks like what I can find has a "bb" prfix on the marking guide.

Comment: Ah yes, Burr-Brown has BB symbol. Edited my answer but this does not change the actual result. [AMS1117 datasheet](http://www.ams-semitech.com/attachments/File/AMS1117_20120314.pdf) has a table indicating that the model with CD suffix is the adjustable one. So probably, the one in your picture is the adjustable one. The last sentence of my answer still applies.

Comment: @RohatKılıç The CD suffix is only for the TO-252 package.

Comment: I can't find any resistors between ground and output.  I'll add another image.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Ah yes, thanks for correcting, but (another datasheet from a Korean Manufacturer)[http://www.htckorea.co.kr/Datasheet/LDO/LM1117.pdf] shows a SOT-223 device with C suffix. Anyway, we all agree that the device is a LM1117.

Comment: @SweetPoontang No! Two resistors: One across the output and 1st (the leftmost - ADJ) pin, one between 1st (ADJ) and ground. Could be in 25R-250R range.

Comment: Isn't the adj lead shared with the ground?

Comment: I think it's a 1.2 v fixed. You see the other 1117c on the board? It has 33 where the 12 is on the 1117c in question and it outputs 3.29v.  I'm guessing it's a bad unit. I get 0.23v on the output and it's severely overheating.  Unless you think an out of spec output capacitor would cause this?

Comment: @SweetPoontang If ADJ pin is grounded then the device is **not** the adjustable version. So, the one in the 1st pic is 1.2V version, and the one to the left in the 2nd pic is the 3.3V version.

Comment: @SweetPoontang If you measure 0.23V across the output then probably there's a short **at the load**, not in the regulator. If the device was damaged then it wouldn't get hot. The culprit is in the sub-circuit that the regulator supplies (Maybe an IC, or a broken/shorted capacitor --I've seen a lot of shorted MLCCs, by the way. There may be one in your circuit as well).

Comment: Thanks. I'm still figuring it out.  What do you think T3 is on this?

Comment: @SweetPoontang Could be a thermistor.